# Adding Google Earth program into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, google-earth

Is it possible to program Google Earth into ArcGIS Pro somehow as to avoid flipping between screens of ArcGIS Pro and Google Earth back-and-forth?

Comment: Google Earth and ArcGIS Pro are both applications that cannot be use 'within' each other.  Is there functionality of GE that you would like to see in Pro?  Are there GE data (KML) that you would like to see in Pro?  Or would you just like to see the imagery base map that GE uses within Pro?

Answer (score 2):

You can add Google satellite data, maps, and hybrid data, etc. to ArcGIS Pro.

From the Add Data drop-down menu choose *Data from Path*.

Enter one of these URLs as the path

```
Google Maps: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={col}&y={row}&z={level}
Google Satellite: http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={col}&y={row}&z={level}
Google Satellite Hybrid: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={col}&y={row}&z={level}
Google Terrain: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={col}&y={row}&z={level}
Google Roads: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=h&x={col}&y={row}&z={level}
```

You may need to zoom out a bit to get the data to draw...